# Remove blank values not the entire column/row in R

Tags: r, heatmap, missing-data

I read in the table using the following code:

```
Data<- read.table("1mo.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Some columns have fewer entries. The problem arises when I try to calculate overlap and intersections, I get the blank value as a common value. So how can I exclude these blanks values without removing the entire column or row?

I am using `RVenn` for making the Venn diagram

```
Dat<-c(Data) 
Test = Venn(Dat) 
overlap(Test)
overlap(Test, c(1,2,3,4,6,7)) 
setmap(Test)
```

Below is the data:

```
dput(Data)
structure(list(W = c("rno-let-7d-3p", "rno-let-7g-5p", "rno-miR-10b-5p", 
"rno-miR-125b-5p", "rno-miR-127-3p", "rno-miR-133a-3p", "rno-miR-192-5p", 
"rno-miR-196b-5p", "rno-miR-223-3p", "rno-miR-22-5p", "rno-miR-26b-5p", 
"rno-miR-29c-3p", "rno-miR-29c-5p", "rno-miR-30c-5p", "rno-miR-30d-5p", 
"rno-miR-30e-5p", "rno-miR-322-5p", "rno-miR-330-3p", "rno-miR-340-3p", 
"rno-miR-3559-5p", "rno-miR-378a-3p", "rno-miR-378b", "rno-miR-383-5p", 
"rno-miR-429", "rno-miR-451-3p", "rno-miR-499-5p", "rno-miR-542-5p", 
"rno-miR-6328", "rno-miR-652-3p", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), 
    Ni = c("rno-miR-125b-1-3p", "rno-miR-127-3p", "rno-miR-133a-3p", 
    "rno-miR-152-3p", "rno-miR-17-5p", "rno-miR-192-5p", "rno-miR-196b-5p", 
    "rno-miR-200a-3p", "rno-miR-20a-5p", "rno-miR-30d-5p", "rno-miR-322-5p", 
    "rno-miR-3559-5p", "rno-miR-499-5p", "rno-miR-505-3p", "rno-miR-542-5p", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", ""), Co = c("rno-miR-107-3p", "rno-miR-133a-3p", 
    "rno-miR-196b-5p", "rno-miR-203a-3p", "rno-miR-24-2-5p", 
    "rno-miR-26b-5p", "rno-miR-423-3p", "rno-miR-500-3p", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), Fe = c("rno-miR-127-3p", 
    "rno-miR-133a-3p", "rno-miR-152-3p", "rno-miR-17-5p", "rno-miR-192-5p", 
    "rno-miR-196b-5p", "rno-miR-200a-3p", "rno-miR-30a-5p", "rno-miR-30c-5p", 
    "rno-miR-30d-5p", "rno-miR-30e-5p", "rno-miR-322-5p", "rno-miR-3559-5p", 
    "rno-miR-499-5p", "rno-miR-542-3p", "rno-miR-542-5p", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", ""), Cu = c("rno-miR-127-3p", "rno-miR-133a-3p", 
    "rno-miR-17-5p", "rno-miR-192-5p", "rno-miR-196b-5p", "rno-miR-1b", 
    "rno-miR-200a-3p", "rno-miR-200c-3p", "rno-miR-22-5p", "rno-miR-30a-5p", 
    "rno-miR-30d-5p", "rno-miR-320-3p", "rno-miR-322-5p", "rno-miR-3559-5p", 
    "rno-miR-499-5p", "rno-miR-500-3p", "rno-miR-542-3p", "rno-miR-542-5p", 
    "rno-miR-6216", "rno-miR-872-5p", "rno-miR-873-3p", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), Al = c("rno-let-7a-1-3p", 
    "rno-let-7c-2-3p", "rno-miR-127-3p", "rno-miR-133a-3p", "rno-miR-17-5p", 
    "rno-miR-181d-3p", "rno-miR-191b", "rno-miR-192-5p", "rno-miR-196b-5p", 
    "rno-miR-200a-3p", "rno-miR-205", "rno-miR-29c-5p", "rno-miR-30d-5p", 
    "rno-miR-30e-5p", "rno-miR-322-5p", "rno-miR-3559-5p", "rno-miR-383-5p", 
    "rno-miR-434-3p", "rno-miR-499-5p", "rno-miR-542-3p", "rno-miR-542-5p", 
    "rno-miR-652-3p", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", ""), Pb = c("rno-let-7a-1-3p", "rno-let-7c-2-3p", 
    "rno-let-7f-5p", "rno-miR-122-3p", "rno-miR-126a-3p", "rno-miR-127-3p", 
    "rno-miR-133a-3p", "rno-miR-144-3p", "rno-miR-148a-5p", "rno-miR-17-5p", 
    "rno-miR-192-5p", "rno-miR-195-5p", "rno-miR-196b-5p", "rno-miR-199a-3p", 
    "rno-miR-200a-3p", "rno-miR-200b-3p", "rno-miR-203b-3p", 
    "rno-miR-20a-5p", "rno-miR-29a-3p", "rno-miR-29b-3p", "rno-miR-29c-5p", 
    "rno-miR-30a-5p", "rno-miR-30d-5p", "rno-miR-30e-3p", "rno-miR-30e-5p", 
    "rno-miR-322-5p", "rno-miR-3559-5p", "rno-miR-383-5p", "rno-miR-423-5p", 
    "rno-miR-450b-3p", "rno-miR-484", "rno-miR-499-5p", "rno-miR-503-3p", 
    "rno-miR-542-3p", "rno-miR-542-5p", "rno-miR-99a-5p"), DU = c("rno-miR-122-3p", 
    "rno-miR-124-3p", "rno-miR-125a-5p", "rno-miR-125b-5p", "rno-miR-126a-3p", 
    "rno-miR-127-3p", "rno-miR-133a-3p", "rno-miR-184", "rno-miR-192-5p", 
    "rno-miR-196b-5p", "rno-miR-200a-3p", "rno-miR-200b-3p", 
    "rno-miR-27a-5p", "rno-miR-29b-3p", "rno-miR-29c-5p", "rno-miR-30a-5p", 
    "rno-miR-30d-5p", "rno-miR-30e-5p", "rno-miR-322-5p", "rno-miR-342-5p", 
    "rno-miR-3559-5p", "rno-miR-375-3p", "rno-miR-383-5p", "rno-miR-451-3p", 
    "rno-miR-484", "rno-miR-499-5p", "rno-miR-542-3p", "rno-miR-542-5p", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-36L))
```

Comment: Please make a complete reproducible example.

Comment: I'm trying to calculate overlap and intersections using RVenn package, however, since I have these blank values in some columns, one of the common values I'm getting is the blank values. I want to exclude these blank values. Makes sense?

Comment: Hello @IvanVechetti, could you please post your question with a sample dataset? It could be `dataset <- data.frame(W = c("rno-miR-340-3p","rno-miR-196b-5p",...), Ni = c(..)) ` or you can use `dput()` . In that way I can help you better.

Comment: Please, write this in your R console: `dput(Data)`. Then copy the output and paste it in your question, but as a code (use three backticks).

Comment: Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 2):

Very hard to tell from your example above, try something like this, I write something that's like your data:

```
x = structure(list(W = c("rno-miR-340-3p", "rno-miR-340-3p", "rno-miR-133a-3p"
), Ni = c("rno-miR-133a-3p", "rno-miR-133a-3p", "rno-miR-500-3p"
), Co = c("rno-miR-500-3p", "rno-miR-500-3p", "rno-miR-196b-5p"
), Fe = c("rno-miR-196b-5p", "rno-miR-196b-5p", ""), Cu = c("rno-miR-133a-3p", 
"rno-miR-133a-3p", ""), Al = c("rno-let-7c-2-3p", "", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
write.table(x,"test.txt",quote=FALSE,sep="\t",row.names=FALSE)
```

And I read it in it, similar to what you have:

```
Data = read.table("test.txt",sep="\t",header=TRUE)
Data
                W              Ni              Co              Fe
1  rno-miR-340-3p rno-miR-133a-3p  rno-miR-500-3p rno-miR-196b-5p
2  rno-miR-340-3p rno-miR-133a-3p  rno-miR-500-3p rno-miR-196b-5p
3 rno-miR-133a-3p  rno-miR-500-3p rno-miR-196b-5p                
               Cu              Al
1 rno-miR-133a-3p rno-let-7c-2-3p
2 rno-miR-133a-3p                
3
```

One way is to fill in the blanks as NA:

```
Data = read.table("test.txt",sep="\t",header=TRUE,fill=TRUE,na.strings="",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
Data
                W              Ni              Co              Fe
1  rno-miR-340-3p rno-miR-133a-3p  rno-miR-500-3p rno-miR-196b-5p
2  rno-miR-340-3p rno-miR-133a-3p  rno-miR-500-3p rno-miR-196b-5p
3 rno-miR-133a-3p  rno-miR-500-3p rno-miR-196b-5p            <NA>
               Cu              Al
1 rno-miR-133a-3p rno-let-7c-2-3p
2 rno-miR-133a-3p            <NA>
3            <NA>            <NA>
```

Then if you wanna do the super venn diagram, you want to iterate through the columns, and omit the NAs:

```
library(RVenn)
ggvenn(Venn(sapply(Data,na.omit)[1:3]))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.  The problem with that is when I try to make a heatmap using RVenn library to calculate overlaps.      > library(RVenn)
Data<- read.table("1mo.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = F, fill=TRUE,na.strings="")
Dat<-c(Data)
Test = Venn(Dat)

#Intersection of all sets
overlap(Test)
#Intersection of selected sets (set names or indices):
overlap(Test, c(1,2,3,4,6,7))
#Set Difference
discern(Test, 7, c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
#HeatMap clustering or not
setmap(Test)   Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : 
  missing values in 'row.names' are not allowed

Comment: Try something like the above.. i am not familiar with venn diagrams so you have to figure out how to use the package.. which is another question altogether i am afraid